# Non-negative forecasts with missing data and clustering

Tags: r, time-series, clustering, forecasting, missing-data

I have a data set of deposits and withdrawals from bank locations, so each record includes a bank identifier, date stamp, number of deposits, and number of withdrawals. I have included reproducible code below.  Note that I have hundreds of days for each of thousands of agents. I have a few questions:

1. I would like to use the forecast package, but I'd like it to take into account day of week patterns and month of year seasonality. The one worry I have about using the "frequency" flag is that I have some randomly missing days for each agent. How should I best deal with this?
2. Deposits and withdrawals cannot be negative so all of the data is non-negative. Can I force the forecast to be non-negative? I know I can use the lambda=0 flag, but this only works when everything is strictly positive (but not applicable in this case because deposits and withdrawals can be zero)
3. Is there anything I can do to increase predictive accuracy by "clustering" banks? Right now, I'm only using a particular bank's data, but given that I have data from thousands of more banks, perhaps I can take advantage of this?

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)

Date = c(today()-1, today()-3, today()-4, today()-5) %>% as.POSIXct
D    = c(10,3,4,3)
W    = c(13,2,4,4)
Bank = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4))
A    = cbind(Date,D,W) %>% as.data.frame 
A$Date = A$Date %>% as.POSIXct(origin="1970-01-01")
B   = A
B$D = B$D - 1
B$W = B$W + 3
A   = A %>% rbind(B)
A   = A %>% cbind(Bank,.)
```

Comment: NB, although there is a good deal of R code here, the questions are statistical.

Comment: What do you mean by '"clustering" banks'? Do you mean running a *cluster analysis* on the banks, or taking into account the *nesting of records within banks*?

Comment: @gung sorry for the confusion -- I mean clustering across banks. For example bank 2's data might be helpful in forecasting for bank 1 and vice versa. Also, I'm a newbie and unfamiliar with the acronym NB -- did I post this in the wrong place? Many thanks!

Comment: No, "NB" stands for [*nota bene*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene). That was a note for any who come across this Q later.